# how to make grouping on the basis of date got in the json object?

Tags: ios, json, swifty-json

I want to display the data as shown in this image.

[image]

My response json is like

```
{
  "transactions" : [
    {
      "amount" : "1.03",
      "transaction_type_id" : "20",
      "transaction_date" : "2017-07-27",
      "value_date" : "2017-07-27",
      "message" : "Amount of interest payment received 03-0128146",
      "debit_credit" : "C",
      "foreign_id" : "45745"
    },
    {
      "amount" : "1.33",
      "transaction_type_id" : "20",
      "transaction_date" : "2017-07-26",
      "value_date" : "2017-07-26",
      "message" : "Amount of interest payment received 03-0128322",
      "debit_credit" : "C",
      "foreign_id" : "46135"
    },
   ],
 "success" : 1
}
```

I want to make the group on the basis of transaction_date. Can anyone guide me how to do this? I am using [swiftyJson](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert your JSON response in Foundation object.

After that apply predicate to achieve the result.

Objective C:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionary]; // assign Foundation object that is converted from json result using SwiftyJson


NSMutableArray *arrTransactionDates = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dictTmp in [dict valueForKey:@"transactions"]) {

    if (![arrTransactionDates containsObject:[dictTmp valueForKey:@"transaction_date"]]) {

        [arrTransactionDates addObject:[dictTmp valueForKey:@"transaction_date"]];
    }
}
NSMutableArray *arrTmp = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=0; i<arrTransactionDates.count; i++) {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"transaction_date=%@",[arrTransactionDates objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSArray *tmp = [[dict valueForKey:@"transactions"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    [arrTmp addObject:tmp];
}
arrTransactionDates = nil;
NSArray *outputArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arrTmp];
arrTmp = nil;
NSLog(@"%@",outputArray);
```

Swift:

```
let dict = [String:Array<Dictionary<String, String>>]() // assign Foundation object that is converted from json result using SwiftyJson


    var arrTransactionDates = [String]()
    for dict in dict["transactions"]! {

        if !arrTransactionDates.contains(dict["transaction_date"]!) {

            arrTransactionDates.append(dict["transaction_date"]!)
        }
    }
    var arrTmp = [Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>]()
    for i in 0..<arrTransactionDates.count {

        var tmp:Array = dict["transactions"]!
        tmp = tmp.filter { ($0["transaction_date"]!).range(of: arrTransactionDates[i], options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]) != nil }
        arrTmp.append(tmp)
    }
    print(arrTmp)
```

Comment: please answer in swift @priya

Comment: in this how to assign my json response to dict directly. Because my dictionary is jsonObject and here dict is [String:Array<Dictionary<String, String>>]().

Comment: You might be getting response from web service so you first need to convert that object in Foundation object and you can achieve this by using siftyJSON. You need to import SwiftJSON and then **let dict = JSON(jsonObject)**

Comment: Replace `[String:Array<Dictionary<String, String>>]()` with object that you get as result from `let dict = JSON(jsonObject)`

Comment: thnak you @Priya

Answer (score 0):

After getting response `jsonObj["transactions"].array ?? [JSON]()` 
here jsonObj is my response Dictionary

```
var dictionaryNew = Dictionary<String, [JSON]>()
var keyNew = [String]()

for obj in self.transactions {

         let date = obj["transaction_date"].string
         if self.dictionaryNew.index(forKey: date!) == nil {

                     self.dictionaryNew[date!] = [obj]
                     self.keyNew.append(date!)

                 }
                  else {

                      self.dictionaryNew[date!]?.append(obj)
                  }
                }

            self.tblAccountStatement.reloadData()
```

in numberOfSections Method

```
return keyNew.count
```

in numberOfRows method

```
return dictionaryNew[keyNew[section]]?.count ?? 0
```

Then after in table Delegate method cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.lblAmountValueDeducted.text = "+ " + (dictionaryNew[keyNew[indexPath.section]]?[indexPath.row]["amount"].string)!
```